# Jquery Tabs Loading Content With AjaxWhile Scrolling

Tags: jquery, jquery-tabs

I am loading content using ajax in Jquery tabs. I want to load more content from the url of active tab and append it to the list and show like in facebook.

How can I combine loading when scrolling and jquery tabs?

Below is the HTML and JS I have used.

HTML:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/EventController?operation=friend">Friends</a></li>
        <li><a href="/EventController?operation=uni">University</a></li>
        <li><a href="/EventController?operation=all">All</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var $tabs = $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
        spinner: "",
        select: function(event, ui) {                
            var tabID = "#ui-tabs-" + (ui.index + 1);
            $(tabID).html("<div class='alert alert-info'><img src='../assets/img/ajax-loader.gif' alt=''> Loading...</div>");                             
        },
        beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
            ui.jqXHR.error(function() {
                ui.panel.html(
                "<div class='alert alert-error'>cannot be loaded</div>" );
            });
        },
        load: function(event, ui){
            $.getScript("../assets/js/bootstrap-ajax.js");               
        }
    });
```

Comment: Infinite scroll are neat, but have some drawback (IMHO) here are some tutorials on how you can achieve this : http://www.jquery4u.com/tutorials/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/

Comment: i thought working with tabs may complicate loading data while scrolling, i will have a look at the link. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I decided not to load more when scrolled to bottom, however the idea is similar. I am just posting back a button with the list items(or divs) like below. This button makes an ajax call and javascript appends content to the tab body.

```
<div id='loadMoreButtonDiv' class='alert alert-info'>
   <center><strong>
       <a class='loadMoreButton' data-target='#ui-tabs-1' href='/EventController?operation=get_events&begin={newBegin}&count={count}'>Load More</a>
   </strong></center>
</div>
```

In Javascript Part I added the following on click handler:

```
$('a.loadMoreButton').on('click', function(event) {
    var $link = $(this);
    var $target = $($link.attr('data-target'));
    $('#loadMoreButtonDiv').remove();
    $target.append("<div id='loadMoreLoadingDiv' class='alert alert-info'><img src='../assets/img/ajax-loader.gif' alt=''> Loading...</div>");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: $link.attr('href'),

        success: function(data) {
            $target.append(data);
        },
        error: function(){
            $target.notify({
                message: {
                    text: 'Server Connectivity Error!'
                },
                type: 'error'
            }).show(); 
            $(this).attr('disabled',false);    
        }
    });
    $('#loadMoreLoadingDiv').remove();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```